# Detect when only preprocessing, i.e. gcc -E

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

I currently invoke clang or gcc as

```
cc -E -DPREPROCESSING ...
```

when debugging macros.

It has occurred to me that the define is redundant. Is there an expression I could write in the source to detect when the compiler will stop after preprocessing, and so drop this definition from my build scripts?

```
#if magic
#define PREPROCESSING
#ending
```

A look at the docs suggests not, but with luck I'm missing something.

Comment: Having this wouldn't have very general value and would introduce build bugs. A build system may chose to preprocess as a separate step, invoking the compiler multiple times. If this feature existed, preprocessing and then compiling separately (to improve cross-platform parallel build performance, for example) would generate different output than preprocessing and compiling in a single execution. That would be very surprising and buggy behavior. How would you treat precompiled headers in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever solution you come up with is going to be compiler-specific, since the C standard does not have anything to say about separate preprocessing.

In gcc, you could implement the magic by adding a custom spec file:

```
%rename cpp old_cpp
*cpp:
%{E:-DPREPROCESSING} %(old_cpp)
```

You would need to tell gcc to use this spec file (`-specs=/path/to/specfile`), unless you compiled your own gcc with the above definition added to the built-in `cpp` spec. If you are using a Makefile, you could add the `-specs` option above to your `CFLAGS`.

(I should add that I don't think this is a particularly good idea. But it is *possible*.)

Comment: I didn't know about spec files. I was hoping for a point fix and you've provided a general mechanism. Very good, thank you